# How can I change blank header in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection:

```
{
     A:1
     B:2
      :3
     D:4
}
```

We need to replace a whitespace with C for example, how can I achieve this?

Like this

```
{
  A:1
  B:2
  C:3
  D:4
}
```

I tried renaming, but it's not possible and the only thing I can think of is rebuilding a collection.

Comment: Which whitespace character is the key eg. space, tab etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution would be to convert the object to an array, and use a regular expression to match fields that do not contain any alphanumeric characters.

This would be able to match any manner of white space, then empty string, etc.

If you can be sure there is only 1 such field in each document, you could use the pipeline form of update to fix the entire collection in one go:

The pipeline below:

- matches every document in the collection
- converts each document to an array using $objectToArray
- examines each key/value pair in the array using $map
- within the map, doesn't touch any field matching the regex
- replace the field name with "C" for fields whose name does not match the regex
- convert the array back to an object

This will match ""," ","  ","\t"(tab character),"\0"(null character), among many others.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$project: {
      docArray: {$map: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"},
          in: {$cond: {
              if: {$regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$this.k",
                  regex: "[A-Za-z0-9]"
              }},
              then: "$$this",
              else: {k: "C", v: "$$this.v"}
          }}
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$docArray"}
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bxKZwflxphX)

Comment: thank u very much. Mongo really can't handle the data the way it was

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator for this.

```
db.collection.update({"_id": 0},{  "$rename": {    " ": "C"  }})
```

Ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mmS2icBgOTO

Comment: Hi THX, but is not my case.

I have this dataset


_id: 654e312d4ff391e4ef2244ad
Id: 2
SepalLengthCm: 4.9
:3
PetalLengthCm: 1.4
PetalWidthCm: 0.2
Species: "Iris-setosa"

and mongo reconize like this,

{
  "Id": 2,
  "SepalLengthCm": 4.9,
  "PetalLengthCm": 1.4,
  "PetalWidthCm": 0.2,
  "Species": "Iris-setosa"
}

him ignore de ":3", despite save them.

Comment: Use whitespace " " as key for value 3, then mongo will save it. Ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8AEsyXheiqh