# How can I attach a header to the column without it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this dataset

```
_id: 654e312d4ff391e4ef2244ad
Id: 2
SepalLengthCm: 4.9
:3
PetalLengthCm: 1.4
PetalWidthCm: 0.2
Species: "Iris-setosa"
```

and mongodb recognize like this,

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "SepalLengthCm": 4.9,
  "PetalLengthCm": 1.4,
  "PetalWidthCm": 0.2,
  "Species": "Iris-setosa"
}
```

him ignore de ":3", despite save them.

I tried rename, but doesn't work because isn't recognized "" by the mongo.
something like:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $rename: { "": "tmpName" } });
```

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $rename: { " ": "tmpName" } });
```

I need put a header in ":3"

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "SepalLengthCm": 4.9,
  "tmpName":3,
  "PetalLengthCm": 1.4,
  "PetalWidthCm": 0.2,
  "Species": "Iris-setosa"
}
```

Comment: What is :3? That seems to be invalid json.

Comment: that's the idea, I need to import a csv without 1 header and I want to fix them.
And mongo saves like this.

Comment: You need `db.collection.updateMany({' ':3}, { $rename: { ' ': 'tmpName' } });`

Comment: Don't work, because him not detect ":3" with  ' '

Comment: Is this question significantly different that your previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77454523/2282634

Comment: no, there are some small differences in the way it was expressed as it doesn't have the full context

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said in your other question that the key was whitepace. In mongodb document keys are strings, any UTF-8 character (except null with $ and . reserved for specific circumstances). Do you know which character it is? It should be very easy to rename the key once you know which character is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$getField` to access the field and `$set` to a new `tmpField`

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "tmpField": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "",
          "input": "$$CURRENT"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OXc51nOrG6d)